# Is there a way to not reload the whole html body with React Routers?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router-dom, react-bootstrap

My React project's App.js file has routes like so:

```
<div>
        <Background />
        <Navbarr />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" component={Home} exact />
          <Route path="/news" component={News} />
          <Route path="/reserve" component={Reserve} />
          <Route path="/admin" component={Admin} />
        </Switch>
</div>
```

In my Navbarr component, I have Links that set the routes, e.g.:

```
<Nav.Link
    href="/news"
    name="news"
    active={active === "/news"}
    onClick={() => setActive("/news")} 
>
News
</Nav.Link>
```

When I click on any of the links, I would like it to just change the component in my <Switch>. Instead, it seems to re-load the whole html body (my background component flashes, even though it has the same picture).

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `react-router-dom`'s `Link` and use `to` prop instead of `href` to use client-side-routing

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

<Link
    to="/news"
    name="news"
    active={active === "/news"}
    onClick={() => setActive("/news")} 
>
News
</Link>
```

---

Alternatively, you can leverage the `as` prop of React-bootstrap

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

<Nav.Link
  as={Link} // --> render as react-router-dom Link
  to="/news"
  name="news"
  active={active === "/news"}
  onClick={() => setActive("/news")}
>
  News
</Nav.Link>
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thanks!